# About octads in Curtis' MOG article

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

In his seminal MOG article, Curtis is able to find the 759 octads forming the $S(5, 8. 24)$ Steiner system. The way in which he got them is clear to me, following the article.
However there's a claim at the beginning which is not fully clear to me:

> We shall produce a subspace, $C$, of $P(\Omega)$ whose
> smallest members are subsets of size eight and shall show, moreover, that $C$ contains
> just 759 of these 'octads'. Clearly no two octads can have five points in common as
> their sum would then have six points or less in it.

It's clear, using symmetric difference, that having five or more points in common would result in a octad sum with six or less points in common. But it's not clear why this could a problem?

Probably because the sum of two octads must be an octad as well, since being a subspace of $P(\Omega)$?

This puzzles me a bit, because later in the article, it's clear octads can share **up to 4 points**, specifically: number of octads sharing one point = $\dbinom{23}4/\dbinom{7}4=$253 and number of octads sharing two points = $\dbinom{22}3/\dbinom{6}3$=$77$.
Also, few lines below it's shown, thanks to a Leech's diagram, that any two octads intersects in $0$, $2$, $4$ or $8$ points.

So this means their sum would result, when sharing 1 point, into no more an octad, and so on and so forth.

So, why having up to 4 points in common is not a problem, while having at least 5 of them could be? Both cases are producing no more octads, when summing them.

Can you please help me in understanding that, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The subspace $\mathcal C$ has sets with at least eight elements in it. The sum of two octads with no elements in common has size $16$, lies in $\mathcal C$, and is not an octad. The octads are minimal elements of $\mathcal C$. Your problems with this paper are all in the first couple of pages. I wonder if this paper is not too advanced for you at the moment. Maybe read about Steiner systems in general first?

Comment: I already read about it in general, and the article approach is purely combinatorial, without requiring any Steiner prior knowledge to it. Worrying about people preparation is not really actually helping a lot, without really answer to problems.

Comment: Well, you are asking a basic question from the first page. Which I answered. I am just trying to suggest you need to be further advanced before looking at the MOG.

Comment: OK I got it, probably: since an octad is minimal in $C$, so we cannot have less than $8$ elements. Sharing one point, using the symmetric difference, would result into a $14$ sets, which is still in $C$. Pushing this argument to $3$ elements, we would get $10$, still in $C$. So the theoretical maximum is $4$ elements shared, leading to an octad, which is minimal. Starting from $5$, we would have $6$ elements, no more in $C$. Please, eventually promote your comment as answer, and I will vote for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of two octads is only defined to be (in Curtis's notation) an element of $\mathcal C$, not an octad. The elements of $\mathcal C$ are subsets of the power set, and the minimal objects in that set have size $8$. If two octads intersected in more than four points, their sum would have fewer than eight points, so cannot be in $\mathcal C$.